# How to use a value in a use state for API URL?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

I am getting trouble with calling the API.
So in the first async await function i got the data of list_id.
Then i put the data inside a useState called listID.
After that i am trying to call an API again with async await function with the value of listID inside the URL. But i am getting an error here. Whats probably the issue?

```
 const [listID, setlistID] = useState();

  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "",
      description: "",
    },
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      if (localStorage.getItem("sessionID")) {
        const createList = async () => {
          try {
            let response = await axios({
              method: "post",
              url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list?api_key=${API_KEY}&session_id=${localStorage.getItem(
                "sessionID"
              )}`,
              data: {
                name: values.name,
                description: values.description,
              },
            });
            setlistID(response.data.list_id);
          } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        };
        createList();
      }
      const getList = async () => {
        try {
          const response = await axios.get(
            `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/${listID}?api_key=${API_KEY}`
          );
          console.log(response);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        }
      };
      getList();
    },
  });
```

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?

Comment: it says the listID is not defined, on the second async await url

Comment: put a console.log inside the getList function for listID and see if the listId is being set correctly everytime

Comment: how do i define the list id inside the get list function?

Comment: Ideally it shouldn't happen. Can you create a short reproducible example here https://codesandbox.io/s/new?file=/src/App.js and share the link

Comment: what if there is no session available ??

Comment: i got the session is in my localstorage..